# Is there a way to specify a "where" condition in XQuery Value function?

Tags: xquery-sql

I have a table with an xml column which contains the below data.

```
<a:Tracking>
    <b:TrackingID>343545</b:TrackingID>
    <b:TrackingID n:id="abc">12345</b:TrackingID>
</a:Tracking>
```

I need to get the value of the node b:TrackingID where it contains an attribute n:id with a value "abc".

I am trying the below code without any success. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://nm.gov/nm/2.0' as b,
    'http://nm.gov/nm/structures/2.0' as n)
    Select @TrackingID = Message.value('(//b:TrackingID)[@n:id = "abc"]', 'varchar(100)')
        From tblData e WITH(NOLOCK)   
        Where ID = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://nm.gov/nm/2.0' as b,
    'http://nm.gov/nm/structures/2.0' as n)
    Select @TrackingID = Message.value('(//b:TrackingID/@n:id[. = "abc"]', 'varchar(100)')
        From tblData e WITH(NOLOCK)   
        Where ID = 12
```